# How to use ClojureScript practically?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am not getting the idea of ClojureScript. For example, I am writing a web application, and I need to write some javascript. Should I use ClojureScript which will generate the javascript for me? Looking for some guidance.

thanks

Comment: You could if you liked.  What do you mean, should you?

Comment: Take a look at this link. Maybe it will give you an idea. https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Rationale

Comment: It depends... If you do not know Clojure I would not even bother with Clojurescript. Clojurescript is basically client side web development for Clojure developers, nothing else

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use it if

- you want to write desktop applications in clojure
- you want to write your entire webapp in clojure, front and back end
- you want to write for a JS based mobile platform like palm etc.
- you are die hard clojure fan... ;)
- you have some algorithm implemented in clojure that you'd like to leverage on a JS platform. (from stand)

Comment: I'd add: you have some algorithm implemented in clojure that you'd like to leverage on a JS platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think ClojureScript shines if your application is a JavaScript-based Rich Internet Application. Think of GMail or Google Maps.

On a side note, ClojureScript competes with CoffeeScript.

Comment: i'll have to check out CoffeeScript, thanks for bringing it up